# How to get all the xml nodes that contain a certain childnode with a certain value in as3?

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to work with XML in flash here and ran into an issue. I need to collect all the nodes in an XMLList that contains a certain childnode with a certain value. For example, from the XML below I just want to get the ''product'' nodes that have 1 as a value for ''amount'', i.e product 3 and 5.

And it's not a typo for product 3... ;(

```
<xml>
    <product>
        <title>Product 1</title>
        <amount>4</amount>
    </product>
    <product>
        <title>Product 2</title>
        <amount>4</amount>
    </product>
    <product>
        <title>Product 3</title>
        <amount>7</amount>
        <amount>1</amount>
    </product>
    <product>
        <title>Product 4</title>
        <amount>4</amount>
    </product>
    <product>
        <title>Product 5</title>
        <amount>1</amount>
    </product>
</xml>
```

Comment: xml.product.(amount == 1) is a start, but it will exclude the one with two amounts.

Answer (score 1):

```
var list : XMLList = xml.product.(amount.(valueOf() == 1).length() > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `xml` is the `XML` object above, then:

```
var xmlList:XMLList = xml.product.(amount == 1);
trace(xmlList.toString());
```

Comment: This will only work if `<product>` does not have more than one `<amount>`.